# Delete a namespace label that has invalid characters

Tags: kubectl

My namespace has a label "some-param=some-value" that I want to remove.

```
kubectl label namespace/myNamespace some-param=some-value-

error: invalid label value: "some-param=some-value": a valid label must be an empty string or consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'MyValue',  or 'my_value',  or '12345', regex used for validation is '(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])?')
```

The invalid character is "=" but I was able to add this label. I just can't remove it.

```
kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.2", GitCommit:"faecb196815e248d3ecfb03c680a4507229c2a56", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:28:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18+", GitVersion:"v1.18.16-gke.2100", GitCommit:"36d0b0a39224fef7a40df3d2bc61dfd96c8c7f6a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-16T09:15:29Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command to remove a label is:

```
kubectl label namespace <namespace_name> <label>-
```

So in your use case it should be:

```
kubectl label namespace myNamespace some-param-
```

You should not use the full key/value pair with the `=` sign in between like `some-param=some-value`.

If you wish to check out more `kubectl label` options than check out [these docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#label).